# Automated update of data documentation when this data is updated

Tags: r, package

I am creating a package and including data of experiments. The experiments are ongoing and therefore the data is going to change in the future.

I am using `roxygen2` for documentation and would like to include a description like the following:

```
#' Data_foo contains the experimental data of [x] participants
```

In future, 'x' is going to change. Of course, I can always manually update this - not a very big problem - or I could simply decide *not* to document like this.

But I simply wondered if this is generally possible, and if - how (e.g., might there be a markdown-like inline-code way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Rd format (which Roxygen produces) supports that.  Use syntax like `\Sexpr{nrow(foo_package::Data_foo)}` where you want `[x]` to appear.

Comment: awesome. for the sake of completeness, it was not sufficient to use `\Sexpr{nrow(Data_foo)}`, but one has to specify the namespace in which to look: `\Sexpr{nrow(foo_package::Data_foo)}`